# How to pass the JS variable +myarray.data[i].id+ value inside SQL select $query?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, xml

I want to pass the value of JS variable `+myarray.data[i].id+` inside SQL select $query i.e I want where `post_id=+myarray.data[i].id+`.

How can I do this? I have tried this but its not working.

ajaxsearchpagination.php file

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxFunction(val)
        {
        var httpxml;
        try
          {
          // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
          httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        catch (e)
          {
          // Internet Explorer
          try
            {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
          catch (e)
            {
            try
              {
              httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            catch (e)
              {
              alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
              return false;
              }
            }
          }
        function stateChanged() 
        {
        if(httpxml.readyState==4)
              {
        /////////////

        var myarray = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
        //alert(httpxml.responseText);
        // Before adding new we must remove previously loaded elements
        for(j=document.getElementById('subject').length-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
        document.getElementById('subject').remove(j);
        }
        var str='';
        var result='';

        for (i=0;i<myarray.data.length;i++)
        {



        <?php
include ('starrating/dbConfig.php');
//Fetch rating deatails from database
$query = "SELECT *, FORMAT((total_points / rating_number),1) as average_rating FROM post_rating WHERE post_id = **'+myarray.data[i].id+'** AND status = 1";
$result = $db->query($query);
$ratingRow = $result->fetch_assoc();
?>           


        } 



        ///////////

        document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML= str;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= result  ;

        if(myarray.value.status1 != 'T'){
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="About " + myarray.value.no_records2 + " & " + myarray.value.no_records + " results " + " Message : "+ myarray.value.message;
        }else{
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="About " + myarray.value.no_records2 + " & " + myarray.value.no_records  + " results " ;
        }
        var endrecord=myarray.value.endrecord 

        document.getElementById("navigation").innerHTML= "<table width=700><tr><td width=350><input type=button id=\'back\' value=Prev onClick=\"ajaxFunction('bk'); return false\"></td><td width=350 align=right><input type=button value=Next id=\"fwd\" onClick=\"ajaxFunction(\'fw\');  return false\"></td></tr></tr> </table>";


        myForm.st.value=endrecord;
        if(myarray.value.end =="yes"){ document.getElementById("fwd").style.display='inline';
        }else{document.getElementById("fwd").style.display='none';}


        if(myarray.value.startrecord =="yes"){ document.getElementById("back").style.display='inline';
        }else{document.getElementById("back").style.display='none';}

              }
            }

            var url="search-backend.php";
        var str=document.getElementById("keyword").value;
        var myendrecord=myForm.st.value;

        url=url+"?txt="+str;
        url=url+"&endrecord="+myendrecord;
        url=url+"&direction="+val;
        url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
        //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=url
        httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
        httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
        httpxml.send(null);
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML=":)...";
        document.getElementById("msg").style.display='inline';

        ////////////////////////////////


        }
        </script>


        </head>

        <body>
        <div id=msg style="position:absolute; width:300px; height:25px; 
        z-index:1; left: 400px; top: 0px; 
        border: 1px none #000000"></div>

        <br><br><br><form name="myForm">
        <input type=hidden name=st value=0>
        <input type="text" onkeyup="ajaxFunction('');" name="keyword" id="keyword" list="subject"  size=70/> 

        <datalist id="subject" >
          </datalist>

        <br><br>
        <div class='t1' id='result'>
        </div>
        </form>

        <div class='t1' id='navigation'>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You have a piece of PHP embedded in your AJAX code, but an AJAX operation does not work like that. Your PHP cannot be embedded in the page you're using - that will execute the PHP at page load time, and will fail because `myarray.data[i].id` does not exist at that time. If you want to do a dynamic lookup in an AJAX operation, move that code to a separate file (e.g. `get_results.php`) and then call it from your AJAX code.

Comment: Tips: (a) you'll need something in your AJAX function to set the URL to call, e.g. `/get_results.php`, (b) use your browser's network tab to look at requests going out from your browser and to debug them, (c) don't concatenate SQL - it is risky, and you're likely to open a SQL injection hole in your application.

Comment: Ok sir i will not add urgent from next time in my question it was my first question & experience on stackoverflow so i was not aware about it,
Thankyou for your help sir, but i am not able to understand what exactly i have to write in code, can you please explain a bit more with a sample code that how to call ajax function from url & what to write in get_results.php & finally how will i pass that myarray.data[i].id into my sql select $query?